# Dell Inspiron 7559 Hard Drive Upgrade

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, dell-inspiron

I want to know if it is possible to replace the SATA HDD on my Dell Inspiron 7559 with a SATA SSD (not an m.2 drive).

Comment: Questions seeking Hardware recommendations are specifically not on topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Dell Inspiron 7559 Hard Drive Upgrade**
>
> I wanted to know if it is possible to replace the SATA hdd with a SATA
>   sdd (not an m.2 drive). If it is possible, what are some potential
>   options.

Yes, this is possible per the specs I see on Dell.com for the particular model you specified where you get to select your configuration option and one listed is with a 256 GB SSD.

[**Dell Inspiron 15 7559 Laptop Specs**](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-15-7559-laptop/pd)

> [image]

---

**Potential Option**

I'd recommend the [Dell Serial ATA Solid State Hard Drive - 128 GB](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&sku=A8527867&mfgpid=245407) as listed on the manufacturer's website.

[**Dell Inspiron 15 7559 Laptop Accessories**](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/PfydFeaturedCategoryResults.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&mfgpid=245407&chassisid=-1&stype=2&Tab=Parts)

> [image]
>
> **Tech Specs**
>
> - **Form Factor:** 2.5 in
> - **Formatted Capacity:** 128 GB
> - **Type:** Solid State
> - **Device Type:** Hard Drive
> - **Interface Type:** Serial ATA

Comment: I see you're going the easy path. But how can you recommend such an overpriced ssd? If this deal included installation/preconfiguration for the notebook, only then it might be an acceptable price for the less tech-savvy user.

Comment: @TJJ Exactly, I went with the Dell recommended SDD drive for the most sensible option that is confirmed to be compatible and not the most cost effective; you are right indeed. Since that was not listed in the scope of the question I went with the most obvious answer that I'd recommend but SuperUser technically isn't for hardware recommendation. Good thoughts and I agree for sure; just trying to answer as fully I could per the wording of the inquiry!!

Comment: I suggest you take out your suggestion and just present the facts, which is To simply link to the Dell accessories website

Comment: @Ramhound let me know if that's better or you are saying something more specific when you get a chance. Thanks!! I just edited my answer.